# Can Array.prototype.map() mutate the array it invokes on?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Mozilla said:

> map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if 
>   invoked, may do so).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Specifically, the third argument the callback was passed is:

> The array map was called upon.

Which I assumed that means the array location in memory is copy into the callback by reference.

So by mutating the third argument, we should mutate the original array, but the following two pieces of snippet give conflicting result:

case 1, re-assigning the third argument did not mutate the original array:

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3];
A.map((v,i,_A) => { 
  console.log("_A is the array map invoked on: ", _A===A); // true
  _A = []; // reassign an empty array
  return v;
});
console.log("'A' did not mutate:", A) // [1, 2, 3] did not mutate
```

case 2, setting the third argument to length of zero mutates the original array:

```js
var B = [1, 2, 3];
B.map((v,i,_B) => { 
  console.log("_B is the array map invoked on: ", _B===B); // true
  _B.length = 0; // clearing the array by setting it zero length
  return v;
});
console.log("'B' has mutated:", B) // [] mutated
```

Clearly in the second case the original array is mutated (the iterator only execute once).
But what am I missing ? Why the conflicting result ?

Comment: Why would reassigning a new value to a the third argument of `Array.prototype.map` which points to the source array change the source array? `A` and the third argument to `Array.prototype.map` are 2 different variables

Answer (score 5):

In case 1, you're only *reassigning* - this is *separate* from mutation. Mutation will only occur if you have syntax like `obj.prop = <someExpression>`. This is what you're doing in case 2 with

```
_B.length = 0;
```

The object in memory that `_B` references will have its `.length` property mutated. But just reassigning a *variable name*, like `_A = []`, won't change whatever `_A` happened to refer to before - the object that was previously referenced by `_A` will be ignored (left unchanged), and future references to `_A` in the scope will refer to whatever was just assigned to `_A`.

This doesn't really have anything to do with `Array.prototype.map` - this is the same sort of behavior you would see for any Javascript object or variable name, eg:

```js
const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
let anotherObj = obj; // references the original object
anotherObj = {};
// a new object is created in memory and assigned to the variable name `anotherObj`
// but this does not mutate whatever anotherObj happened to refer to before
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, things aren’t exactly pass-by reference as you may be familiar with. A local copy of the reference to A is created in the local scope of the callback. See this answer for more info: [Does Javascript pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Therefore, when you reassign _A to an empty array, you are just telling the reference copy to point to a new empty array. However, the old reference to A still exists and is untouched.

When you mutate length, you are actually mutation the object the _A refers to.